# Running SQL query for common table in all databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to run SQL query to populate result against a common table in all databases.. however it is resulting in false output

```
Create table #userid (dbname varchar(50), username varchar(50))
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'IF ''?'' NOT IN (''master'',''security'',''tempdb'')
BEGIN
inset into #userid
select ''?'' dbname, username from zuserdb where username IN (''a1234'',''b1234'')
END'
Select * from #userid
DROP table #userid
```

Above Code isn't generating right output .. multiple rows are being generated however user actually doesn't exist in database. Any suggestions

Comment: sp_MSforeachdb is undocumented and should be treated as such

Comment: any alternative @sql_underworld

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why that is happening it is undocumented, but here is one workaround.

Use three part identifier in table name. Considering `zuserdb` is present in `dbo` schema in all the database.

```
CREATE TABLE #userid
  (
     dbname   VARCHAR(50),
     username VARCHAR(50)
  )

EXEC Sp_msforeachdb
  'IF ''?'' NOT IN (''master'',''security'',''tempdb'',''model'',''msdb'')
BEGIN
insert into #userid
select ''?'' dbname, username from ?.dbo.zuserdb where username IN (''a1234'',''b1234'')
END'

SELECT *
FROM   #userid

DROP TABLE #userid
```

Added `model` & `msdb` databases also in exclude list because those are also system databases